# How merge new records without calculate all the records again

Tags: sql, postgresql, merge, postgresql-9.4

I have a table of cars position with millions of rows and thousand of cars_id

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/LEIK11250)**

```
ID  Car_ID  .... other fields
 1    A
 2    B
 3    B
 4    A
 5    A
```

I need create routes for each car. So with this query:

```
WITH cte as (
     SELECT ID, CAR_ID,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAR_ID ORDER BY ID) as rn
     FROM myTable
)
SELECT o.CAR_ID, o.ID, d.ID
FROM cte as o       -- origin
LEFT JOIN cte as d  -- destination
  ON o.rn = d.rn - 1
 AND o."Car_ID" = d."Car_ID"
WHERE d.ID IS NOT NULL
```

I insert the routes in the `route_sources` table

```
 ROUTE_SOURCE_id   CAR_ID    ORIGIN_ID   DESTINATION_ID
       1             A          1              4
       2             B          2              3
       3             A          4              5
```

The problem is when enter new cars positions I need to check what routes arent already created and add it to the `route_sources` table.

For examples new rows

```
ID  Car_ID
 6    A
 7    B
 8    B
```

Then I only need to add the following routes:

```
ROUTE_SOURCE_id   CAR_ID    ORIGIN_ID   DESTINATION_ID
       4             A          5              6
       5             B          3              7
       6             B          7              8
```

I know how to do merge, note version is 9.4 so `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT UPDATE (and ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING), i.e. upsert.` isn't available.

But my problem is I don't want to calculate the million of routes every time just to add the new routes.

*Consider the car_position table get around 6000 new records for minute.*

I have think in two option:

- create one insert trigger in `car_positions` table, and with each insert search for previous car position and create the route and insert into `route_sources`.
- create a car_log table where I save the last ID used to create a route for each car and then the create route process will check for ID newer than those ID.

But not fan of doing a select for each insert, and the car_log idea looks too complicated. Any ideas?

Comment: Your 'Id' looks like a serial. If you use it as an identifier for locations, an object (car) can never go *back* from loc_b to loc_a, if b > a

Comment: @joop yes, id is serial. there are other field to indicate `(x,y)`. But the route is `id_a -> id_b` when add `id_c` need to add `id_b-> id_c`

Answer (score 0):

http://rextester.com/NFTKN29525

Not pretty, but generally create a CTE where you look at the last destination of each car, and pair it with the new ones. In the case of 'B', where we had to enter 2 records, the last destination from the query was not updated, which is why I had to let it choose from new data if it can. This approach created a record where destination = origin, which is why I needed the CTE, from which I could later filter out what was necessary.

In order to abide by Stackoverflow rules, here is the query itself:

```
WITH new_routes AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        n."Car_ID",
        greatest(first_value(r.destination_id) OVER (PARTITION BY r."Car_ID" ORDER BY r.destination_id DESC),
                 lag(n.destination_id, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY n."Car_ID" ORDER BY n.destination_id)) AS origin_id,
        n.destination_id
    FROM newData n
    JOIN result r ON r."Car_ID" = n."Car_ID" AND r.destination_id<n.destination_id
)
INSERT INTO result ("Car_ID", origin_id, destination_id)
SELECT * FROM new_routes WHERE origin_id<>destination_id
ORDER BY destination_id;
```

assuming that `result` is your previous working table, and `newData` is the new data that just came in.

In case you have a new car `C`, you can use your previous method of creating the routes for it. Use plpgsql to control this decision.

Comment: The only problem is the "new data" is inserted on the same table. So there is no way to know which one are the new rows. I will need to keep track of when was the last time the process run, but seem like a good solution.